# How to destroy a component on navigation

Tags: nativescript-angular

I need to destroy a component on navigating away from it but I cannot figure out how to do it. I've tried clearHistory: true in RouterExtensions, but it doesn't work. The flow of our program is this:

Dashboard > link to Component1

Component1 > Save takes the user back to Dashboard.

If the user clicks the link to go back to Component1, I get an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError because the memory of the component is still resident.

Comment: Using modals is an interesting idea, but wouldn't work in this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

It is bit tricky to remove a page from the navigation history in nativescrupt angular. I would suggest you to create a modal page for Component1, save it and when user close the modal, take it back to Dashboard.

or you need to handle the change detection manually, for further reading, you can refer [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my immediate problem by redesigning the page to use calculated values based on the data rather than ui state settings from the ngrx store which, as I thought about it, is a more stable solution.

I left the question up because I was curious if there was a way to remove pages from the navigation history.